# Is there a SOAP::Lite equivalent library in ruby?

Tags: ruby, soap

I want to build a SOAP client using ruby. I tried using the soap4r library to generate ruby classes out of the WSDL file, but the issue with this was that all the methods it generated were of optional kind, instead of NAME/VALUE pairs. Given that some methods have a very large number of arguments, many of which are optional, I would prefer to use something like SOAP::Lite(Perl Library) which does not depend on WSDL file and accepts arguments as NAME/VALUE pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not actually used this myself, but I remembered hearing about it the other day: [Handsoap](https://github.com/unwire/handsoap). Check it out and see if it fits your needs! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at [Savon](http://github.com/rubiii/savon/).